# How can I efficiently store rapidly changing time-series data in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, time-series, hardware, database

I have live time-series data generated by a light sensor, and presented as a rapidly changing (refreshing about every 20 milliseconds) variable in the public javascript file. How can I store them into mongo efficiently? Could anybody give me some suggestions about the best practices?

Comment: This question is unclear. First we need to know what "rapidly changing" actually means. It could mean anything between once per minute and once per microsecond. Then we need to know what information you are actually storing in the database - just the current value or a history of all values? And then we need to know what you are actually going to do with the data - how you want to query it is the most important factor when designing a MongoDB database schema.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good case for using mongodb's [Capped Collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/).

> Capped collections are fixed-size collections that support high-throughput operations that insert and retrieve documents based on insertion order. Capped collections work in a way similar to circular buffers: once a collection fills its allocated space, it makes room for new documents by overwriting the oldest documents in the collection.

You could insert each light sensor measurement as a new document in a Capped Collection, then you can efficiently retrieve the measurements in the same order as they were inserted, and also not have to worry about running out of storage space.